# htaccess redirect folder to same folder with variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was wondering how i could go about redirecting

https://www.segmento.com.au/special-edition/

to

https://www.segmento.com.au/special-edition/?reset_wp_cart

I've tried this:

```
Redirect 302 /special-edition/ /special-edition/?reset_wp_cart
```

But it's a never ending loop of ?reset_wp_cart?reset_wp_cart?reset_wp_cart?reset_wp_cart?reset_wp_cart?reset_wp_cart?reset_wp_cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Redirect`. Use `mod_rewrite` rule with a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !reset_wp_cart [NC]
RewriteRule ^special-edition/?$ /$0?reset_wp_cart [L,R=302,NC]
```

Make sure this your first rule and you completely clear your browser cache before testing.